# How to copy component to attribute

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Actually I need something like caching 
Now  I have 2 components which are being created dynamically on `change` event of `inputselect`

```
 <aura:attribute access="GLOBAL" name="CriteriaTiles" type="Object" description="tile component"/>
    <aura:attribute access="GLOBAL" name="cacheCriteriaTiles" type="Aura.Component" description="tile component"/>
    <aura:attribute access="GLOBAL" name="criteriaList" type="Aura.Component" description="component with criteria list"/>
    <aura:attribute access="GLOBAL" name="cacheCriteriaList" type="Aura.Component" description="component with Cache criteria list"/>
    <aura:attribute access="GLOBAL" name="resultsListView" type="Object" description="component with search results"/>
```

markup of ui

```
<div class="slds-col">
                    <div aura:id="def_criteria" style="width:30%">
                        {!v.CriteriaTiles}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col--bump-left slds-p-right--large slds-p-left--medium c-min-width-col">
                    <div aura:id="criteria_table" >

                        {!v.criteriaList}
                    </div>

   <ui:inputSelect aura:id="selectObj" class="slds-select c-select" label=""  change="{!c.createCriterias}" />
  createCriterias : function (component, event, helper) {
       helper.createDefCriteria (component, event); 
       helper.createCriteriaTable (component, event); 
    },
```

**creating  criteriaTiles**

```
createDefCriteria : function (component, event) {
    $A.createComponent(
    "c:CriteriaTiles",
    {},
    function(newComp) {
        //var content = component.get("v.defCriteria");
        var selectObj = component.find("selectObj").get("v.options");
        var selectObjValue = selectObj[0].selected;
        console.log(selectObjValue);
        if (selectObjValue) {
            console.log('enter choose primary object');
            component.set("v.CriteriaTiles", null);
        } else {
            console.log('enter else');
            component.set("v.CriteriaTiles", newComp);
        }
    }
    );
},
```

**creating  criteriaList**

```
createCriteriaTable : function (component, event) {
    console.log('enter createCriteriaTable');
    var currValue = component.find("selectObj").get("v.value");
    $A.createComponent(
    "c:CriteriaList",
    {
        "primaryObjName" : currValue
    },
    function(newComp) {

        var selectObj = component.find("selectObj").get("v.options");
        var selectObjValue = selectObj[0].selected;
        console.log(selectObjValue);
        if (selectObjValue) {
            console.log('enter choose primary object CriteriaTable');
            component.set("v.criteriaList", null);
            component.set("v.resultsListView", null);
            component.set("v.errorMessage", null);
        } else {
            console.log('enter else CriteriaTable');
            component.set("v.criteriaList", newComp);
            component.set("v.resultsListView", null);
            component.set("v.errorMessage", null);
        }
    }
    );
},
```

So when they are  created dynamically everything works fine and they are displayed correctly

But  on some actions I want to delete this two components and display another one and then return back those 2 components with their  input values.
I try to just copy them to identical attributes like this

```
  <aura:attribute access="GLOBAL" name="CriteriaTiles" type="Object" description="tile component"/>
    <aura:attribute access="GLOBAL" name="cacheCriteriaTiles" type="Aura.Component" description="tile component"/>
    <aura:attribute access="GLOBAL" name="criteriaList" type="Aura.Component" description="component with criteria list"/>
    <aura:attribute access="GLOBAL" name="cacheCriteriaList" type="Aura.Component" description="component with Cache criteria list"/>

    var cacheCriteriaList = component.get("v.criteriaList");
    var cacheCriteriaTiles=component.get("v.CriteriaTiles");
    component.set("v.cacheCriteriaList", cacheCriteriaList);
    component.set("v.cacheCriteriaTiles", cacheCriteriaTiles);
 component.set("v.criteriaList", null); 
component.set("v.CriteriaTiles", null);
```

and then when i need it return them  back

```
  component.set("v.criteriaList",component.get("v.cacheCriteriaList"));
        component.set("v.CriteriaTiles",component.get("v.cacheCriteriaTiles"));

        console.log("finished REsult", component.get("v.criteriaList"));
```

But it's completely not gonna work!
I see result object of component.get("v.criteria List") on console but don't see any result on ui
what can be the matter, any ideas< maybe some tips?

Comment: not sure if this will solve your issue because it's early on a friday, but I think when getting attributes of dynamically created components you need to use getReference(), not get() ?

Comment: @ChristianCarter - Is a comment somehow more valid on say Monday afternoon? Poor Friday, always getting a bad rap....